# Very slow MySQL query execution

Tags: mysql, bash, ubuntu

I have created a database in MySQL on Ubuntu to get an overview which comics I own and to get some details like the title of an issue, it's writers, editors, pencilers etc. No problems with the query itself but with the amount of time it takes to execute it.

This is the query:

```
select 
  issue.issueNR, 
  issue.issueName, 
  series.seriesName, 
  writer.writerName, 
  editor.editorName, 
  penciler.pencilerName, 
  letterer.lettererName, 
  colourist.colouristName,
  coverArtist.coverArtistName
from 
  writer, writerLookup, 
  editor, editorLookup, 
  penciler, pencilerLookup, 
  letterer, lettererLookup, 
  colourist, colouristLookup,
  coverArtist, coverArtistLookup,
  issue, 
  series 
where 
  (issue.issueID = writerLookup.issueID and writerLookup.writerID = writer.writerID) 
  and (issue.issueID = editorLookup.issueID and editorLookup.editorID = editor.editorID) 
  and (issue.issueID = pencilerLookup.issueID and pencilerLookup.pencilerID = penciler.pencilerID)
  and (issue.issueID = lettererLookup.issueID and lettererLookup.lettererID = letterer.lettererID)
  and (issue.issueID = colouristLookup.issueID and colouristLookup.colouristID = colourist.colouristID)
  and (issue.issueID = coverArtistLookup.issueID and coverArtistLookup.coverArtistID = coverArtist.coverArtistID)  
  and issue.seriesID = series.seriesID;
```

The result:

```
+---------+---------------------------+---------------------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+---------------+-----------------+
| issueNR | issueName                 | seriesName                | writerName  | editorName  | pencilerName   | lettererName      | colouristName | coverArtistName |
+---------+---------------------------+---------------------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+---------------+-----------------+
|       1 | X-Men                     | X-Men                     | Stan Lee    | Stan Lee    | Jack Kirby     | Sam Rosen         | Uncredited    | Jack Kirby      |
|       1 | X-Men                     | X-Men                     | Stan Lee    | Stan Lee    | Jack Kirby     | Sam Rosen         | Uncredited    | Sol Brodsky     |
|       1 | The Long Way Home, Part 1 | Buffy, the Vampire Slayer | Joss Whedon | Scott Allie | Georges Jeanty | Richard Starkings | Dave Stewart  | Jo Chen         |
|       1 | The Long Way Home, Part 1 | Buffy, the Vampire Slayer | Joss Whedon | Scott Allie | Georges Jeanty | Jimmy Betancourt  | Dave Stewart  | Jo Chen         |
|       1 | The Long Way Home, Part 1 | Buffy, the Vampire Slayer | Joss Whedon | Scott Allie | Georges Jeanty | Richard Starkings | Dave Stewart  | Georges Jeanty  |
|       1 | The Long Way Home, Part 1 | Buffy, the Vampire Slayer | Joss Whedon | Scott Allie | Georges Jeanty | Jimmy Betancourt  | Dave Stewart  | Georges Jeanty  |
+---------+---------------------------+---------------------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+---------------+-----------------+
6 rows in set (2 min 55.66 sec)
```

As you can see it takes almost 3 minutes to generate 6 rows and that's really too slow, especially because this is not the complete query because I also have an inker, tpb, ...

You can find the bash script which I use to create the tables here: http://textuploader.com/degt

Is there some way to make the query or my database more performant?

Comment: Do you have indexes on all the files you're using in the joins?

Comment: The query takes 55.66 sec, not 3 minutes, the difference is transfering from server to browser and rendering html. You are joining 14 tables, and not even using a real JOIN. Do you use index?

Comment: Can you put EXPLAIN before the select and put the result up here. Also, they way you join tables is NOT recommended.

Comment: @DanFromGermany, it does say 2 min before 55.56 sec ;)

Comment: @MarcB Nope, no indexes.

Comment: Then definitely add indexes. General rule of thumb is to ALWAYS have an index on any field involved in a `where` or a `join` operation.

Comment: Timo, you probably dont want to hear this but, I would recommend you to start over. This is a terrible query and very hard to read. Take your time to read about joining tables with indexes, and you will have a query that probably runs in less than 1 second if you set it up properly. This query is to bad to even begin to fix IMHO.

Comment: @KayNelson This is the output of the EXPLAIN http://textuploader.com/deg0 First time btw that I'm trying to create something like this so I knew I would have to start over a couple of times :)

Comment: @MarcB I have added index on fields that I use in the where clause but it still takes 55 seconds to execute. Something else I should look after?

Comment: just how many records are there in this db? if the size of the indexes exceeds your db's memory setup, then you'll be hitting disk and get painfully bad execution times.

Comment: @MarcB Every table (19 to be exact) contains maximum 3 rows but when I delete the database, it says that 19 rows are affected.